# Contractual async and sync code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, interface

There are a lot of questions asking whether to mix async and sync code.

Most answers say it is a bad idea to expose sync wrappers for async methods, and to expose async wrappers for sync methods.

However, none of the answers address the specific scenario where you HAVE to mix async and sync code, and how to avoid common pitfalls that arise because of it.

See the following example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IContract signatory = new SyncSignatory();
        signatory.FullfillContractAsync().Wait();
        signatory = new AsyncSignatory();
        signatory.FullfillContractAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

interface IContract
{
    Task FullfillContractAsync();
}
```

---

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class AsyncSignatory : IContract
{
    public async Task FullfillContractAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class SyncSignatory : IContract
{
    public Task FullfillContractAsync()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class SyncSignatory : IContract
{
    public Task FullfillContractAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
    }
}
```

In this example, SyncSignatory and AsyncSignatory represent two interchangeable classes because they perform similar functions, however they perform these functions in different manners - synchronously and asynchronously.

How do you mix contractual sync and async code while avoiding common pitfall scenarios?

How about a user that expects syncSig to run async, but instead it runs sync?

What about a user who could have optimized syncSig by running it async, but not longer does because they assume it already runs async?

Comment: @DanWilson Revised.

Comment: I don't really see the problem.  The only thing the consumer needs to know about the method is its parameters, name, and return type.  What the method does internally shouldn't matter to the the caller

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get an answer without a specific use-case in your example which currently is too generic. Who is going to be calling these methods? Do you expect this to be in a hot path of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, none of the answers address the specific scenario where you HAVE to mix async and sync code, and how to avoid common pitfalls that arise because of it.

That's because it's a bad idea. Any mixing code should be fully temporary in nature, existing only during a transition to asynchronous APIs.

That said, I have written [an entire article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

> How do you mix contractual sync and async code while avoiding common pitfall scenarios?

As I describe in my [blog post on async interfaces](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-1-inheritance-and-interfaces.html), `async` is an implementation detail. A task-returning method *may* complete synchronously. However, I'd recommend avoiding *blocking* implementations; if they're not avoidable for some reason, then I'd carefully document that they exist.

Alternatively, you *could* use `Task.Run` as the implementation; I don't recommend this (for reasons [detailed on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)), but it is an option if you *have* to have a blocking implementation.

> How about a user that expects syncSig to run async, but instead it runs sync?

The calling thread is blocked synchronously. This is usually only a problem for UI threads - see below.

> What about a user who could have optimized syncSig by running it async, but not longer does because they assume it already runs async?

If the calling code is ASP.NET, then it should call it directly and `await`. Synchronous code will be executed synchronously, which is desirable on that platform.

If the calling code is a UI app, then it needs to be aware that there are synchronous implementations, and can call it wrapped in a `Task.Run`. This avoids blocking the UI thread regardless of whether the implementation is synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: In your very last paragraph, are you saying that with a UI it's a good idea to wrap a call to a method that you *think* is async (.e.g `Task DoSomethingAsync()`) because that method could *still* be implemented to run synchronously (e.g. `{ return Task.CompletedTask; }`)?  Do you only do this at the boundary between your code and third-party code since you don't know how the latter implements your interface vis-a-vis sync vs async?  If so, wouldn't this mean you'd be wrapping all your await calls to the third-party code in your UI with an outer `Task.Run`?

Comment: @rory.ap: No, I'm saying that *if* the implementation is synchronous (or may be synchronous), the UI app should use `Task.Run`. The vast majority of Task-returning method do not fall into this category.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the proper way to mix async and sync?

Mostly yes. If you have a common interface, where some implementations will be able to provide a synchronous implementation, but others only an asynchronous one, returning `Task<T>` makes sense. A simple `return Task.FromResult` can be appropriate. But there are exceptions, see below.

> How about a user that expects syncSig to run async, but instead it runs sync?

There are some aspects of interfaces that cannot be expressed in code.

If it is a requirement of your `IContract` that it not block the calling thread for more than X milliseconds before returning a `Task` (not a reasonable hard requirement in this exact form, but you get the basic idea), and it blocks the thread anyway, that's a contract violation and the user should report it as a bug to whoever implemented syncSig.

If it is a requirement of your `IContract` that it not throw synchronous exceptions, that any errors be reported using `Task.FromException` or equivalent, and your syncSig throws a synchronous exception anyway, that too is a contract violation.

Other than that, if syncSig simply immediately returns the correct result, there's no reason why that should bother any user.

> What about a user who could have optimized syncSig by running it async, but not longer does because they assume it already runs async?

If syncSig running synchronously doesn't cause any problems, it doesn't matter, it doesn't need to be optimised yet.

If syncSig running synchronously does cause problems, basic debugging tools should soon enough tell the developer that syncSig is causing problems and should be investigated.

Comment: How does the first scenario I linked avoid more pitfalls than the second? (Running the sync code in SyncSignatory sync vs running it async).

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I'm not seeing any links in your question, and I'm not able to guess what you mean from your comment.

Comment: Oh it is not a link, it is an edit with more code at the bottom of the question. Wrap it with async code or keep the sync code?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Oh... `Thread.Sleep(5000); return Task.FromResult<object>(null);` blocks the current thread, `return Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));` blocks a background thread. Presumably you're not simply sleeping, but let's say you're doing something that you cannot speed up. If your callers need you to return a task quickly, you'd need to use `Task.Run`. If your callers expect a completed task when your function returns (because you promised them execution would be synchronous), you'd need to avoid `Task.Run`. There's no simple rule here, it depends on your callers' expectations.

Comment: Yeah, in this case the method name ends in Async so the caller probably expects the second scenario rather than the first. Which of the two is more correct in that it avoids more common pitfalls? My thoughts are the second because it aligns with what the user thinks, but the first is less prone to hanging too so idk.

Comment: Also why would this be the correct way of handling this for cases where there is a contract? One example that does this differently could be the  System.Net.WebClient class, such class exposes both sync and async methods.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera I'm not going to pretend to know which pitfalls are more common. I've seen them both and I'd readily believe either is more common. I can try to help give you the information needed for you to determine the answer yourself for your scenario, but the additional information you've now provided doesn't tell me enough to answer in more detail than I've already done, sorry. You should have a better view of your users than I do.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera "Also why would this be the correct way of handling this for cases where there is a contract? One example that does this differently could be the System.Net.WebClient class, such class exposes both sync and async methods." -- In that case, there isn't a contract that both the synchronous and asynchronous methods must adhere to. There's one contract for the synchronous ones, and one for the asynchronous ones.